# Get a cookie's single value javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I already have a script that check for the cookies existence,
but i need it to get the cookies value so i can use it in a url like this:

```
var lang = cookievalue;
location.replace(window.location.protocol+"//"+document.domain+"/"+cookievalue+window.location.pathname);
```

so what would be the easiest way to simply get the value of a cookie through javascript, everything i've looked for seems to involve spliting the value and stuff,w hich is not necesary since theres simply only one value (en,fr,es etc)

Comment: "splitting the value and stuff" is necessary even when you have just one cookie with one value. Try `alert( document.cookie )` and you'll see how it looks like.

Comment: i don't mind using jquery but no plugins, please. and if i can specify the cookie by name, and it only has one value..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function getCookieValue(key) {
  var cookies = document.cookie.split('; ');
  for (var i = 0, parts; (parts = cookies[i] && cookies[i].split('=')); i++) {
    if (decode(parts.shift()) === key) {
      return decode(parts.join('='));
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function decode(s) {
  return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
```

Then, to get a value for a cookie named `my_cookie_name`, you would use `getCookieValue('my_cookie_name')`.

Also as an **alternative**, you can use the [`jquery-cookie`](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin. It's very simple to use (`$.cookie('my_cookie_name')`) and lightweight.

Comment: Did you see anyone talking about jquery anywhere?

Comment: Point is, this question is about cookies and javascript, and you just link a jquery plugin. There is more to JS than only jquery.

Comment: @dombenoit: I've included the relevant part of the plugin, no jQuery.

Comment: There you go, now that's better ;)

Comment: @dombenoit: Although I still don't understand why 3 downvotes for a simple suggestion.

Comment: this might be a noob question but how would i add the cookie value that this returns into location.replace(window.location.protocol+"//"+document.domain+"/"+cookievalue+window.location.pathname);

Comment: @theatomicdude: `location.replace(window.location.protocol+"//"+document.domain+"/"+getCookieValue('name_of_your_cookie')+w‌​indow.location.pathname);`

Comment: console gave me this: `Syntax error at line 1: unexpected character: U+200C
ain+"/"+getCookieVal‌​ue('TR_LNG')+windo`

Comment: @theatomicdude: Can you post more code on jsfiddle.com so that I can check it? I've executed that function locally and it works just fine.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Q6hvp/ thats a fiddle with just my javscript code and its showing errors, but i cant figure out what it is

Comment: @theatomicdude: You had some invalid characters in your code, I've updated the fiddle and simplified some parts of your code. It should be fine now: http://jsfiddle.net/Q6hvp/2/