# asp javascript checking if Request.cookie didn't find anything

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cookies

I am using asp (javascript language) and am trying to get a cookie that sometimes exists and sometimes doesn't. When it doesn't exist I am having a hard time detecting.. What does `Request.Cookies(key)` return when it doesn't find something?

```
var session = Request.Cookies('sessionId');

if (session !== "" && typeof session !== "undefined" && session !== null) {
    Response.write("cookieAppSession = " + session + ";");
}
```

This is printing `cookieAppSession = ;` for me. Printing `typeof session` gives me object. How can I tell if its this empty object?

Comment: I'm pretty new to asp and just am using it for this one thing so I may have the terms incorrect.. but it is asp code with `<% @ LANGUAGE = JavaScript %>`

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't anything in the Cookies collection it will return a null value.

In C Sharp:

```
if(Request.Cookies["sessionId"] != null)
    Label1.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["sessionId"].Value);
```

There's a discussion of this for javascript here: [Get a cookie's single value javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059958/get-a-cookies-single-value-javascript)

Here's a great overview of how cookies work in Asp.Net .Net Framework 4: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194(v=vs.100).aspx